# How to speed up Google Appengine and remove time-outs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, colors

I have a Flask app deployed on Appengine standard environment (free trial) at http://hue-histogram.appspot.com/. The purpose of the app is to calculate hue histograms as per this article https://fstoppers.com/education/art-and-science-photography-color-theory-411739

While the app runs smoothly on localhost (Flask server), on Appengine it only works with small images (about 2000 x 1500 pixels and 2MB files). With larger images (4000 x 2500 pixels, 5MB filesize) it always time outs with

> 500 Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

Here's the code from localhost. The only difference on Appengine is that I savefig and open histogram.png to /tmp.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file #, Response
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
#from matplotlib.figure import Figure


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/hue-histogram', methods=['POST'])
def histogram():
    fig = hue_histogram(request.files['image'])
    im = Image.open('histogram.png')
    img_io = io.BytesIO()
    im.save(img_io, 'PNG')
    img_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/png')    
# THIS CODE DID NOT RETURN CORRECT IMAGE+PLOT OVERLAY
# HAD TO USE SAVEFIG TO HISTOGRAM.PNG INSTEAD
#    output = io.BytesIO()
#    FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(output)
#    return Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')

def hue_histogram(uploaded_image):
    N = 24

    im = Image.open(uploaded_image).convert("HSV")

    radii = []
    i=0
    while i < N:
        radii.append(0)
        i = i + 1

    hdat,sdat,vdat = im.split()
    for h,s,v in zip(hdat.getdata(),sdat.getdata(),vdat.getdata()) :
        i = int(h / (255 / N))
        radii[i] = radii[i] + 1          #simple frequency based histogram
#        radii[i] = radii[i] + s          #saturation weighted

    width,height = im.size
    diameter = min(width,height)
    left = (width - diameter)/2
    top = (height - diameter)/2
    right = (width + diameter)/2
    bottom = (height + diameter)/2

    im = Image.open(uploaded_image).convert("RGB")

    # Crop the center of the image
    im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    npImage=np.array(im)
    # Create same size alpha layer with circle
    alpha = Image.new('L',im.size,0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
    draw.pieslice([0,0,diameter,diameter],0,360,fill=255)
    # Convert alpha Image to numpy array
    npAlpha=np.array(alpha)

    # Add alpha layer to RGB
    npImage=np.dstack((npImage,npAlpha))
    im = Image.fromarray(npImage)

    # Compute pie slices
    theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
    width = 2 * np.pi / N
    colors = plt.cm.hsv(theta/2/np.pi)

    radiimax = max(radii)
    i=0
    while i < N:
        radii[i] = radii[i] / radiimax
        i = i + 1

    fig = plt.figure(dpi=150)

    ax0 = fig.add_axes([0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 0.5])
    ax0.imshow(im)
    ax0.axis("off")


    ax = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9], polar=True, label="polar")
    bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=1.3, color=colors)

    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
    ax.set_facecolor("None")
    ax.axis("off")

    plt.savefig("histogram.png", bbox_inches = "tight")

    return 'fig'


if __name__ == '__main__':
#    app.debug = True #Uncomment to enable debugging
    app.run() #Run the Server
```

Would appreciate any help as to how I can optimize the code and/or the Appengine deployment so that it can process even large JPEG files. A lot of the code is glued together from different pieces of code here on StackOverflow so I guess there is a lot of potential to clean this up however it's already beyond and above my beginner skills. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine has by default a request time limit of 60 seconds / request. There are more quotas regarding the size of the request / time of the response etc.. You can check all quotas and limitations [**here**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits).

As the calculation of a histogram is a process than can take more time I recommend you to change your [app.yaml configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements) from `automatic_scaling` to `basic_scaling.`

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types) if you use `basic__scaling` your requests can run for up to 24h.

**EDIT:**

You could try to increase the max_instances  and the idle_timeout parameters( even though I think that what you set is more than enough ). I would try to see [where are those memory leaks](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks).

I would also want to mention that there are some certain configuration and limitation that you should take into account while [using the matplotlib in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#matplotlib).

For example, as it is stated in the official documentation :

> The pylab and matplotlib.pyplot modules are stateful and not thread safe. If you use them on App Engine, you must set threadsafe: false in app.yaml, and be aware that the plotter state will be preserved between requests on the same instance. For example, you will need to call pyplot.clf() at the beginning of each request to ensure that previous plots are not visible. It is recommended that you use the thread-safe object-oriented API instead of the stateful pyplot API.

I am not able to see in your code that you are calling  `pyplot.clf()` method.
Did you also set `threadsafe : false` in your `app.ymal` file?

Comment: I tried this so my app.yaml now looks like below and it seems as if the app now handles a bit larger files (up to ~5MB), but still anything over ~5MB and I get timed out. 
`runtime: python37
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 10`

Comment: Here's the Stackdriver Log with some memory usage information: While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

Comment: I have edited my answer with more information, as I was able to find further documentation and I saw some little irregularities in your code, also. I hope that these will solve your issue.

Comment: So based on the log info in my previous comment I also added `instance_class: B8` to app.yaml and it now handles even 10MB files. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: threadsafe setting in app.yaml only applies to Python 2.7 environment, not 3.7 which I'm using.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked out. I will leave these info in the answer, as it may be helpful for other community members that are facing the same issue as you, but using Python 2.7